# Android SQLite - changing journal_mode

Tags: android, sqlite, pragma

I am trying to alter the journal_mode for my database, through code. I tried SQLiteDatabase.execSQL("PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF") but it fails because, the expression "PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF" returns a result (I verified this from the terminal), and so Android thinks this is a query and complains that I should be using execQuery instead. But what I am trying to execute isn't a query.

I also tried compiling the pragma expression to a SQLiteStatement and invoked the execute method, but same result.

Can someone suggest any alternatives to make this work through code?

Thanks,
Ranjit

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are suffering from this problem that the [execSQL docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) talk about:

> When using enableWriteAheadLogging(), journal_mode is automatically managed by this class. So, do not set journal_mode using "PRAGMA journal_mode'" statement if your app is using enableWriteAheadLogging()

Check that you are not using write ahead logging and then it might work.

Update: As Ranjit said in the comments, this should work:

```java
Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF", null); 
c1.close();
```

Comment: I don't set this option anywhere in my code. Per Android documentation, enableWriteAheadLogging was introduced only at API level l1 or Android 3.0 (http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) and I am still compiling for Android 2.1, API level 7

Comment: This works.                                                       Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF", null);
c1.close();

Comment: Just in case it's useful for somebody (Ranjit doesn't seem to use SO very much)... In my code I've tried to do `db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF", null); c1.close();` and after that if I queried the pragma (omitting =MODE) it got back to persist. But if I do `c1.moveToNext(); c1.getString(0);` it does work :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the next command:

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF;");
```

(No need to create a `Cursor` as it is suggested in one of the comments to [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163681/2308720))

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase?hl=en there is no `rawExecSql()` method.

Comment: @user149408, you are right. Changed to execSQL -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase?hl=en#execSQL(java.lang.String)