# How do I force sqlite to merge journal file into main database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an app that writes to the databases with transactions. I understand that sqlite will write to the journal file and then merge it in once the journal file gets to a certain size. I also have functionality that will try and copy the database file to another location. My problem is I can't find a way to force sqlite to merge the journal into the main database.

All of my queries look something like this

```
SQLiteDatabase database =null;
try{
    database = getReadableDatabase();

    //PERFORM SOME INSERT

   }
   catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error with insert");
   }
   finally {
        if( database != null){
            database.close();
        }
  }
```

After these methods execute I will close the app and inspect the directory where the app saves its database. I can see the database file and database-journal.

I am trying to do something like

```
public void copyDatabase(){
    //FORCE MERGE

    //DO OTHER OPERATIONS
}
```

Does somebody have any ideas on how to merge the journal file when needed?

Comment: Do each of the tables have the same attributes?

Comment: What do you mean same attributes? Each table has its own unique structure

Comment: So, you want to place all the records of one table into another regardless of the column data matching or not? It would be helpful for the question if you posted your schema for each of the tables.

Comment: Sorry Ill go edit my question. The journal file is the one that sqlite uses to maintain commits. It automatically gets merged once it gets too large. However if I try to interact with the database before the auto merge I wont get all the data.

Comment: The solution should be independent of what tables I have in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The journal only contains information about uncommitted transactions. If you are sure the database is not opened from anywhere, the journal file is not in use and it is safe to simply copy the core database file.

**Details**

Sqlite has [multiple journal modes](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode), including `DELETE` which deletes the journal when the last transaction terminates.

However, the [default journal mode](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/config.xml#L1213) under android is `PERSIST` meaning that the journal file is not automatically deleted by the database engine even when it is not currently in use.

It is possible to change the journal mode in android: [Android SQLite - changing journal_mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163320/android-sqlite-changing-journal-mode)

```
db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF", null).close();
```

Note the [warning](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29), however:

> When using enableWriteAheadLogging(), journal_mode is automatically managed by this class. So, do not set journal_mode using "PRAGMA journal_mode'" statement if your app is using enableWriteAheadLogging()

Answer (score 0):

USing the C API of SQLite, you can execute the vacuum command as follows:

> sqlite3_exec(db, "VACUUM", 0, 0, 0);

This corresponds the (shell) command:

> sqlite3 database.db vacuum

Both clean up the database and remove the journal file as part of that.